# How to prevent Solr timeout during updates via php solarium

Tags: php, solr, solarium

I am new to Solr. I am using the php library [solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/) to run a huge bundle of updates to a Solr instance. The problem is, that I am receiving a HttpException within my php-script:

`Solr HTTP error: HTTP request failed, Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received`

I am parsing a CSV-file with about 300,000 datasets and firing them in small bundles. I tried 50-1000. But it always runs into a timeout.

How do I prevent timeouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to use the [BufferedAdd plugin](http://wiki.solarium-project.org/index.php/V3:BufferedAdd_plugin). This prevents timeouts was created for such cases.

Comment: Your link is dead. Please update the link target if you can.